# How to change keyboard shortcut in Budgie Files 3.26.3?

Tags: shortcut-keys, filemanager, budgie

I am using Ubuntu Budgie 18.04.

I would like to change default keyboard shortcut for action "go to next tab" from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

[image: Shortcuts Help]

I went to global Settings > Devices > Keyboard but I can't find this shortcut to change.

[image: Settings > Devices > Keyboard]

I thought I could use dconf editor but I don't know where to look in the settings tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Budgie desktop is using the default gnome file manager, nautilus. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to change these key bindings. These key combinations appear to be hard coded in nautilus, and cannot be changes without editing the source code and recompiling the program.

Some time ago, [gnome developers decided not to enable Ctrl+Tab for tab switching](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=498974#c9).

For the Gnome editor gedit, a [third party plugin allows to enable tab switching with Ctrl+tab](https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-control-your-tabs). I am not aware of any tool that would enable this for nautilus.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is very disappointing, especially "gnome developers decided" and "combinations hard coded"... This is very anti user friendly, more over - I didn't know that Budgie uses Nautilus, its "About" menu does not mention this name (instead it is called "Files" - nonsense!). Such a promiscuity, but worst shit is that its hard coded :(

Comment: Also in Gnome, it is being named "Files" although the executable remains "nautilus" thus far. I agree: the trend where some software becomes less configurable is a pity.

Answer (score 0):

**My Friend here is the right way to change or create new "bind" for your keys :**

> Example file for services that require global keybinding services drop
> a .bde extension file into /etc/budgie-extras-daemon/bde/ or
> /usr/share/budgie-extras-daemon or the install location appended with
> bde either/both toggle / command need to be specified
>
> [Daemon] shortcut=key shortcut to bind e.g. s
> toggle=GSettings full-gsettings-path
> key-is-bool-to-toggle-when-shortcut-activated command=command line to
> execute when shortcut activated onlyactivate=GSettings
> full-gsettings-path key-is-bool-bind-shortcut-only-when-true
> overlay=GSettings full-gsettings-path key-is-string-set-to-empty used
> with onlyactivate to set key to '' if true or reset to default key
> value if onlyactivate is false name=short name to describe what this
> shortcut is all about.

**This documentation is in the directory :**

> /usr/share/budgie-extras-daemon

**This works for all shortcuts that are internal to the system Ubuntu Budgie**

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you want to say, and I can't find `/etc/budgie-extras-daemon/bde/` nor `/etc/budgie-extras-daemon/` nor `/usr/share/budgie-extras-daemon/` directories